# Can multiple domain point to one public html?

Tags: web, load-balancing

I am intented to develop a website for multiple client. The website need to be accessed by different domain ([www.abc.com](http://www.abc.com), [www.def.com](http://www.def.com)), each domain has each server to maintain performance, and I found this load balancing method. So, my question is, can this different domain point to the same public html directory, if i use load balancing method?

Comment: Probably www.serverfault.com is a better place to ask this.

Comment: ok, i will ask this question there

Answer (score 0):

You don't really need a load balancer for pointing multiple domains to a single public html.
Just host your website on a server and add that server's [IP address](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IP_address) as an [A record on DNS](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/dns/dns-records/dns-a-record) of both of your domains.
You can also use a [reverse proxy](https://www.cloudflare.com/learning/cdn/glossary/reverse-proxy) if you want to hide your server's IP address.

Comment: i need load balancer because each domain has very high traffic, it is like real time website

Comment: What load balancer or technique are you thinking to use for your website?

Comment: so i need for each domain that want to access the same public html, has their own server to do each domain's workload